# How do I make a Flat Design Menu bar?

Tags: css, html, menu, nav

Hello I am trying to make a website but my menu bar is not doing what it should. This is what it should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDvwo.png

But instead it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Ya8.png

Here is my code:

## HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Colve</h1></div>
<nav>
<ul class="menu1">
<li><a class="button" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="button" href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a class="button" href="#downloads">Downloads</a>
<li><a class="button" href="invasion.html">INVASION</a></li>    
</li><li><a class="button" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<section id="about">
<h1>About-Colve</h1>
<p>Colve is a company that gives you the things you want in one place</p>
<p>Created by Bradley Beeke</p>
</section>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
html {
font:12pt Lato, sans-serif;
min-height:100%;
background-image:linear-gradient(45deg,#3498db,#2ecc71);
}
body{margin:0px;}

header{
background-color:white;
Color: #FFDF00;
float:left;
padding-left:5px;
display:block;


}
nav {
background-color:white;
float:right;
padding-right:5px;
height:60px;
display:block;
width:100%;
float:right;

}
nav a   {
text-decoration:none;
list-style:none;
color:#FFDF00;
font-size:20px;
padding:8px;

}
nav li:hover, a:hover {color:#998100;}
li{display:inline;}
section { margin-bottom: 1000px; padding-top: 150px; float: left; }
```

Please can you help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/saziz/1/edit)

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Colve</h1> <!-- remove the </div> present here -->
<nav>
<ul class="menu1">
<li><a class="button" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="button" href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a class="button" href="#downloads">Downloads</a>
<li><a class="button" href="invasion.html">INVASION</a></li>    
</li><li><a class="button" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

In the nav css, make width to be auto

```
nav {
background-color:white;
float:right;
padding-right:5px;
height:60px;
display:block;
width:auto;
float:right;
}
```

Add `width: 100%;` in `header {}` because currently the header is not properly aligned.
The HTML is not well constructed. Please remove the extra  and  from the code.

Comment: The HTML here is still bad.  The unordered list elements are messed up.

Comment: @DerekCurtis Yes, the HTML is still bad. I was looking at the header part to align it properly. Will update the answer now again

Comment: @DerekCurtis By just correcting the HTML it won't work. He needs to do changes in the CSS as well. I have attached JSBIN demo link. Check there

Answer (score 0):

Well, right off the bat your HTML is invalid.. I see two immediate problems.

First, the  closing tag after your closing H1 tag cannot be there (it looks like that was just an accident anyway).

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Colve</h1></div>
```

Second, the closing  that starts this line doesn't make any sense.. Remove it.

```
</li><li><a class="button" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

Oh, I lied.. there's a 3rd.. There's no closing  tag for this element.

```
<li><a class="button" href="#downloads">Downloads</a>
```

Other than that, your HTML looks fine to me at a quick look, but in the future you may want to bookmark this site:

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

After you correct those problems with your HTML, update your question if you're still having problems.

Comment: The validator got rid of my HTML5 so I fixed the errors my self but that does not help my to get the menu working

Comment: @DoomFire106 For nav{} you have specified width : 100%; which will make the menu to always align below the header. So change the width as i mentioned in my below answer and bingo it will work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gRX6w/2/ <-- obviously you'll need to complete your styling, but I think your problem was with your layout.